Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed:
flutter build apk --release
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3616 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed: ProcessException: Failed to find "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot" in the search path.
Command: C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot
Target android_aot_release_android-x64 failed: ProcessException: Failed to find "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot" in the search path.
Command: C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.


Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           58.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
I am unable to build the apk in latest flutter version
flutter --version
Flutter 3.24.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cf269e36d (8 days ago) • 2024-09-03 14:30:00 -0700
Engine • revision a6bd3f1de1
Tools • Dart 3.5.2 • DevTools 2.37.2

run the app using
flutter run --release --no-tree-shake-icons
command

try
flutter upgrade
it works for me
